# Android dev: Creating a sqlite database for word games, no user inputs

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a simple game where users guess words. Now, I'm thinking using database to store these words to be guessed.

My problem is the tutorials that are available in the web show how to create a database and save user inputs to that database. They create, for example, a DBHelper.java in src, extends it to SQLiteOpenHelper, override the methods. Back to a specific activity, create an instance of DBHelper, then create the db, open the writable, insert user inputs, close db.

But what I think I only need to do is create a database, insert words in it, then make my app retrieve words from this database.

Am i just wondering if what i'm planning to do is right:
1. create a DBHelper.java in src, extends the class to SQLiteOpenHelper
2. define needed Strings like name of database etc.
3. Create a constructor and override the onCreate and onUpgrade methods
4. CREATE A LOADWORDS METHOD this is where i will insert my words to the database.
5. on my main activity(the first screen on my app) I will create an instance of DBHelper and call the onCreate and loadWords method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// you would want an onCreate and onUpgrade method for best practices,, here's a partial look of what you want...

public class DBManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    static final String TAG = "DBManager";
    static final String DB_NAME = "words.db";
    static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    static final String TABLE = "words_table";
    static final String C_ID = "id";
    static final String C_WORD = "word";

    public DBManager(Context context)
    {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " (" 
               + C_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
               + C_WORD + " TEXT)";

    db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
    }

        //**** Code Insert Word and Retrieve Word Methods *****//

        //**** End Code Insert Word and Retrieve Word Methods *****//
}
```